# Spring security authentication using LDAP

Tags: ldap, spring-security

I am new to spring security and i've tried to run a sample application based on the spring-security ldap example. Below is my configuration of the applicationContext-security.xml:

```
<http>
        <intercept-url pattern="/Login.jsp" filters="none"></intercept-url>
        <intercept-url pattern="/nnn/**" access="ROLE_ADMIN" />
        <intercept-url pattern="/common/**" access="ROLE_USER" />
        <form-login login-page="/Login.jsp" authentication-failure-url="/Login.jsp?login_error=1"
                    default-target-url="/common/home.jsp"/>
        <logout logout-success-url="/Login.jsp" invalidate-session="true"/>
    </http>

    <authentication-manager>
        <ldap-authentication-provider group-search-filter="member={0}"
            group-search-base="ou=groups"
            user-search-base="ou=people"
            user-search-filter="uid={0}" />
            <authentication-provider ref='secondLdapProvider' />
    </authentication-manager>

    <ldap-server ldif="classpath:users.ldif"  port="33389"/>

    <b:bean id="contextSource" class="org.springframework.security.ldap.DefaultSpringSecurityContextSource">
        <b:constructor-arg value="ldap://localhost:33389/dc=springframework,dc=org"/>
    </b:bean>
```

I've used the user.ldif file as it is.
The application runs successfully if I use the default values. But if I put any other value in place of springframework, say google, in the ldif file and in the contextSource bean in the applicationContext-security.xml, then I get the below error:

```
Your login attempt was not successful, try again.

Reason: [LDAP: error code 32 - NO_SUCH_OBJECT: failed for SearchRequest baseDn :
'2.5.4.11=people,0.9.2342.19200300.100.1.25=google,0.9.2342.19200300.100.1.25=org' filter : '(0.9.2342.19200300.100.1.1=rod)' scope :whole
subtree typesOnly : false Size Limit : no limit Time Limit : no limit Deref Aliases : deref Always attributes : : Cannot find a partition for
2.5.4.11=people,0.9.2342.19200300.100.1.25=google,0.9.2342.19200300.100.1.25=org:
org.apache.directory.shared.ldap.exception.LdapNameNotFoundException: Cannot find a partition for
2.5.4.11=people,0.9.2342.19200300.100.1.25=google,0.9.2342.19200300.100.1.25=org at
org.apache.directory.server.core.partition.DefaultPartitionNexus.getPartition(DefaultPartitionNexus.java:1082) at
org.apache.directory.server.core.partition.DefaultPartitionNexus.hasEntry(DefaultPartitionNexus.java:1037) at
org.apache.directory.server.core.interceptor.InterceptorChain$1.hasEntry(InterceptorChain.java:167) at
```

Could someone please tell me why am I getting the above error...

---

This is the ldif file:

```
dn: ou=groups,dc=google,dc=org
objectclass: top
objectclass: organizationalUnit
ou: groups

dn: ou=people,dc=google,dc=org
objectclass: top
objectclass: organizationalUnit
ou: people

dn: uid=rod,ou=people,dc=google,dc=org
objectclass: top
objectclass: person
objectclass: organizationalPerson
objectclass: inetOrgPerson
cn: Rod Johnson
sn: Johnson
uid: rod
userPassword: koala

dn: uid=dianne,ou=people,dc=google,dc=org
objectclass: top
objectclass: person
objectclass: organizationalPerson
objectclass: inetOrgPerson
cn: Dianne Emu
sn: Emu
uid: dianne
userPassword: emu

dn: uid=scott,ou=people,dc=google,dc=org
objectclass: top
objectclass: person
objectclass: organizationalPerson
objectclass: inetOrgPerson
cn: Scott
sn: Wombat
uid: scott
userPassword: wombat

dn: cn=user,ou=groups,dc=google,dc=org
objectclass: top
objectclass: groupOfNames
cn: user
member: uid=rod,ou=people,dc=google,dc=org
member: uid=dianne,ou=people,dc=google,dc=org
member: uid=scott,ou=people,dc=google,dc=org

dn: cn=teller,ou=groups,dc=google,dc=org
objectclass: top
objectclass: groupOfNames
cn: USER
member: uid=rod,ou=people,dc=google,dc=org
member: dianne=rod,ou=people,dc=google,dc=org

dn: cn=supervisor,ou=groups,dc=google,dc=org
objectclass: top
objectclass: groupOfNames
cn: ADMIN
member: uid=rod,ou=people,dc=google,dc=org
```

Instead of google, it was springframework in the original file from the sample application. Am I missing something in this...

Answer (score 1):

You need to set `root` to desired base-dn/suffix (dc=google,dc=org, in your case) to get it to work. so, in all, there are three places where you need to make changes:

1. the root in the ldap-server
2. the context source definition
3. the ldif file

The default root is `dc=springframework,dc=org` that is why you did not need to set it in the example you posted. To use any other base dn, follow the example ldap-server definition below:

```
<security:ldap-server id="dummyLdap" ldif="classpath:users.ldif" port="33389" root="dc=stackoverflow,dc=com">
```

Answer (score 0):

A search request must contain a base object, a scope, and a filter at minimum. The base object that is specified in your query does not exist, therefore the search fails. Error code 32 is, as you can see, 'no such object', in this case, the base object.