# How to obtain all LDAP groups in spring security

Tags: java, active-directory, spring-security

How to obtain all Active Directory groups (Not just related to a current user)? I'm using spring security ldap. Could you provide some examples?

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://whathaveyoutried.com)

Comment: Did you go through other threads where people have provided examples and questions? For example http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7417177/spring-security-authentication-using-ldap

Answer (score 5):

Spring Security LDAP is great if you want to *authenticate* users, but if you just need to *query* LDAP (in this case for all groups), then [Spring LDAP](https://docs.spring.io/spring-ldap/docs/current/reference/) (not to be confused with [Spring Security LDAP](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.security/spring-security-ldap)) is better suited for your purposes.

Example:

```
import static org.springframework.ldap.query.LdapQueryBuilder.query;

LdapTemplate ldapTemplate; // Injected via Spring

// Using Java 8 lambda expressions
ldapTemplate.search(
    query().where("objectclass").is("group"),
    (AttributesMapper<String>) attributes -> attributes.get("cn").get().toString()
);
```

Answer (score 1):

What you can do is write an implementation of `LdapAuthoritiesPopulator` that matches the `DefaultLdapAuthoritiesPopulator` implementation with an extra method to retrieve all roles.

```
public class ExtendedLdapAuthoritiesPopulator
        implements LdapAuthoritiesPopulator {

    // Copy implementation of DefaultLdapAuthoritiesPopulator (omitted).

    private String allAuthorityFilter
        = "(&(objectClass=group)(objectCategory=group))";
    public void setAllAuthorityFilter(String allAuthorityFilter) {
        Assert.notNull(allAuthorityFilter,
                       "allAuthorityFilter must not be null");
        this.allAuthorityFilter = allAuthorityFilter;
    }

    public final Collection<GrantedAuthority> getAllAuthorities() {
        if (groupSearchBase == null) {
            return new HashSet<>();
        }
        Set<GrantedAuthority> authorities = new HashSet<>();
        if (logger.isDebugEnabled()) {
            logger.debug("Searching for all roles with filter '"
                         + allAuthorityFilter + "' in search base '"
                         + groupSearchBase + "'");
        }
        Set<String> roles = ldapTemplate.searchForSingleAttributeValues(
                groupSearchBase,
                allAuthorityFilter,
                new String[0],
                groupRoleAttribute);
        if (logger.isDebugEnabled()) {
            logger.debug("Roles from search: " + roles);
        }
        for (String role : roles) {
            if (convertToUpperCase) {
                role = role.toUpperCase();
            }
            authorities.add(new SimpleGrantedAuthority(rolePrefix + role));
        }
        return authorities;
    }

}
```

In your spring security configuration change the `DefaultLdapAuthoritiesPopulator` to your new implementation.

An additional property can set the `AllAuthorityFilter` which filters which groups will be returned.

You may prefer your implementation to just retrieve the `String` based role names instead of the `GrantedAuthority` instances.

Answer (score -1):

Check this interface:
http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/docs/3.1.x/apidocs/org/springframework/security/ldap/userdetails/LdapAuthoritiesPopulator.html

and this class default:

http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/docs/3.1.x/apidocs/org/springframework/security/ldap/userdetails/DefaultLdapAuthoritiesPopulator.html

it can be helpful

Comment: Yes, i see how to get groups for a particular user. Problem is that i haven't found the way to obtain list containing all existing ldap groups.

Answer (score -1):

Getting all LDAP Groups might require different authentication than getting de groups of a user that logs in. One can user Spring LDAPTemplate.

```
import java.util.List;
import javax.naming.directory.SearchControls;
import org.springframework.ldap.core.LdapTemplate;
import org.springframework.ldap.core.support.LdapContextSource;
import org.springframework.ldap.filter.AndFilter;
import org.springframework.ldap.filter.EqualsFilter;

public class LDAPListGroups {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

        LdapContextSource ldapContextSource = new LdapContextSource();
        //LDAP URL
        ldapContextSource.setUrl("ldap://localhost:10389/dc=example,dc=com");
        //Authenticate as User that has access to this node in LDAP
        ldapContextSource.setUserDn("uid=admin,ou=system");
        ldapContextSource.setPassword("secret");
        ldapContextSource.afterPropertiesSet();
        LdapTemplate ldapTemplate = new LdapTemplate(ldapContextSource);
        ldapTemplate.afterPropertiesSet();

        GroupAttributesMapper mapper = new GroupAttributesMapper();
        SearchControls controls = new SearchControls();
        AndFilter filter = new AndFilter();
        filter.and(new EqualsFilter("objectclass", "groupOfNames"));

        List<Group> groups = ldapTemplate.search("ou=groups", filter.encode(), controls, mapper);
        for (Group group:groups)
        {
            System.out.println(group.getLongID());
        }
    }
}



import javax.naming.NamingEnumeration;
import javax.naming.NamingException;
import javax.naming.directory.Attributes;

import org.springframework.ldap.core.AttributesMapper;
import org.springframework.ldap.support.LdapEncoder;

public class GroupAttributesMapper implements AttributesMapper<Group> {

    public Group mapFromAttributes(Attributes attributes) throws NamingException {
        Group groupObject = new Group(attributes.get("cn").get().toString().toUpperCase());
        NamingEnumeration<?> it = attributes.get("member").getAll();
        while (it.hasMoreElements())
        {
            String elem = (String) it.next();
            elem = elem.substring(elem.indexOf("cn=")+3);
            elem = elem.substring(0,elem.indexOf(","));
            elem = LdapEncoder.nameDecode(elem);
            groupObject.addMember(elem);
        }
        return groupObject;
    }

}
```

Comment: Group;
GroupAttributesMapper;
 
And where would u get these imports from?

Comment: You didn't mention two imports in the solution you have provided